# beginTransaction(); not recognized in intellIj 4.0.3

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, intellij-idea

I'm just trying to create a simple single fragment. I'm using intellij as my IDE. When I call beginTransaction(), the code isn't resolved and asks me to create a class with beginTransaction extended.

...

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = new fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    TestFrag testFrag = new TestFrag();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.testFrag, testFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

...

Comment: Your code is incorrect. Try this - FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Comment: Ah, thanks, but it still says unresolved.

Comment: Intellij 4.0.3? The current version is 12.1.6....

Comment: Check your import. Do you use support-v4-library?